# Que diseñar primero ¿UML o Modelo Entidad Relacion?

Tags: mysql, uml

estoy preparando el proyecto final de DAW y me he llegado al momento de hacer el diseño del programa y el modelo entidad relación.

Perdonar si la pregunta es muy obvia, pero me ha surgido la duda.

¿Que debo diseñar primero, el modelo entidad relación o el diagrama UML?

Gracias de antemano por vuestra respuesta.
Saludos!

Comment: UML se usa para modelar un sistema (que requisitos tiene, como va a funcionar, etc.) es algo que debe estar claro antes de diseñar la BD, dicho de otro modo el diseño de la BD depende de las características del mismo. Entonces UML primero...

Answer (score 1):

Primero es el diagrama UML. A medida que vas realizando este diagrama, veras que vas identificando ciertas partes que luego acabarán siendo un dominio de base de datos (tabla) o relaciones, entre otras muchas cosas.

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero que deberás hacer es el diagrama UML. Al finalizarlo a través de ese diagrama podrás ir identificando las tablas necesarias en tu entidad relación.